# Why camera is not working from image picker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

Here is the code, I am using for image_picker to display a camera or gallery image. Using additionally as a .dart file in the main function I am running this code under RunApp().

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';
class Display_Image extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Display_ImageState createState() => _Display_ImageState();
}

class _Display_ImageState extends State<Display_Image> {
  File _image;
  void ImageGrab(int i)
  async {
    setState(() {
      ShowSpinner=true;
    });
    try
    {
      if(i==1) {
        File gallerfile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery);
        _image=gallerfile;
        setState(() {
          ShowSpinner=false;
        });
      }
      else {
        File gallerfile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.camera);
        _image=gallerfile;

      setState(() {
        ShowSpinner=false;
      });}
      //print('Selected image path: ${gallerfile.path}');

    }
    catch(e)
    {
      print(e);
    }

  }
  bool ShowSpinner=false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Test'),
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: ShowSpinner,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            //SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Container(
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(width: 20,),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.camera),
                    onPressed: (){
                      ImageGrab(0);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 120,),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.image),
                    onPressed: (){
                      ImageGrab(1);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20,)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            //SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Expanded(
              child:Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: _image==null?Text('Image Appears here'):Image.file(_image),
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the UI image:

[image]

Now the two problems, I am facing are:
1. When I use the camera button to display the camera image, camera UI opens, I capture the image, press the check button and the UI keeps loading but the image is not displayed.
2. When I restart the app and re-run it, again the UI keeps loading, even if I press gallery button which works well when I run the app from the scratch, it displays a message in the console saying:

> I/flutter (14072): PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is
>   already active, null)

Note this happens only while encountering the second case of the cases I have mentioned.
Moreover, I am using the version number **image_picker: ^0.5.4+1** as I am using mlkit libraries of firebase, which throws a huge error with lots of messages if I use image_picker's new versions.

Kindly look into this and let me know how do I proceed further with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score -2):

So here's I solved this problem.
Points to ensure are:

1. The version of the image_picker must be the latest updated version.
2. Android-X Compatability errors may come while doing the same thing. These errors appear as explained in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254).

To resolve the problem number 2, you need to make some very important changes and to the best of my knowledge, you can only do this by doing the following changes:

Step 1. Go to gradle.properties under android folder, and add the following piece of code:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Step 2. Now go to build.gradle under android and not under the app->build.gradle. While looking into the file make sure it starts with the word builscript (In this way you can ensure you're at the right build.gradle file.)

Step 3. Ctrl+A everything in that file, note that ctrl+A everything you need to erase off all the content and paste this piece of code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**A very important point to note is that during the process of compilation, chances are that you will see this warning message in complete red. Please don't get scared of it and let the whole compilation complete, before jumping to any conclusions. Although it comes in red, it won't stop your compilation as you will see in the bottom a turning circle that will show the progress of compilation. Right after that, it will disappear and you will be able to run the App. Here's the warning message:**

> Note:
>   C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}' Note:
>   C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\mlkit-0.15.0\android\src\main\java\com\azihsoyn\flutter\mlkit\MlkitPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details.

And Boom! that's it. Trust me this will definitely solve your problems.

In case you still struggle with any such problems try to implement some of the other solutions mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254#issuecomment-553000221) as well.